# UIButton added in keywindow never fired

Tags: ios, uibutton, window, touch

I want to add button on most Top Window.

If I add `UIButton` in `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.` 
It shows as I expect. But never fired. 
I tried to add tap gesture on `UIView`. never fired. 
any `UIView` on top window. never fired.

How could I make it?
I don't have navigationcontroller so it's not an option for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the top view controller of the application?

Comment: @deadbeef Sorry, I did mistake. It's working.

Comment: @satheeshwaran Sorry.

Comment: I did. Thanks. @bRIMOsBor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did mistake.

I added button on UIView, which is coming from outside from screen. 
Yes, I made animate that view with using set NSLayoutConstraint.

I tried animation option for allowUserInteraction but no luck.

My button's disappearing animation is written in complete callback of appearing animation, and it's staying 2 seconds with using animate's delay property.

It may cause that problem.

I ended up split those animataion. It's working fine now.